# Passing arrays of structs to OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I often use a struct to encapsulate a piece of graphics data, like colors/pixels.  Provided they use the expected data type, can I pass arrays of these to OpenGL, or does this violate strict aliasing rules?  For example:

```
typedef struct Color {
    uint8_t v[4];
} Color;

Color colors[200];

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    /* populate color data */
}

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, colors);
```

Versus the less abstracted version:

```
uint8_t colors[200 * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < 200 * 4; i++) {
    /* populate color data */
}

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, colors);
```

Comment: From GL's perspective, there is no difference between either of those two things. `colors` is the address of a contiguous block of memory. The only thing that *might* be different between the two has to do with the alignment of an array of structs, but in this case I really cannot see a `uint8_t` causing alignment issues, `uint8_t`'s can be aligned to any arbitrary 1-byte boundary on most platforms, having 4 of them even improves the odds that no alignment changes are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it work, as long as there is no padding.  Double-check that `4 == sizeof (Color)`.

In some cases you might also need to use `glPixelStorei` with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to let OpenGL know that array elements in sequential rows are close-packed, without extra padding at the end of a row.

The actual read operations in OpenGL and other library functions aren't visible to the C++ compiler, so strict aliasing doesn't apply to them.  The rule does apply to your code, but since you are passing a `const void*`, the compiler has to assume it can alias anything, and not perform reordering across the library call.

Comment: This. And in addition most compilers provide a compiler specific attribute for struct packing, i.e. elements are tightly packed into a struct without gaps in between.