# Passing an array of nested structs as uniform in glsl opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, glsl, compute-shader

I have seen a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983404/passing-arrays-of-structs-to-opengl), but it does not seem to solve my problem.

I have a bunch of structs, that are aggregative.

```cpp
struct Lambert {
  vec3 albedo;
};
struct Metal {
  vec3 albedo;
  float roughness;
};
struct Dielectric {
  float ref_idx;
};
struct Material {
  int type; // 0: lambert, 1: metal, 2: dielectric;
  Lambert lam;
  Metal met;
  Dielectric die;
};
struct Sphere {
  vec3 center;
  float radius;
  Material mat_ptr;
};
struct Material {
  int type; // 0: lambert, 1: metal, 2: dielectric;
  Lambert lam;
  Metal met;
  Dielectric die;
};
struct Sphere {
  vec3 center;
  float radius;
  Material mat_ptr;
};
struct Hittable {
  int type; // 0 sphere, 1, other
  Sphere sp;
};

uniform Hittable hittables[20];
```

I am trying to pass value to uniforms.
I tried to pass the value to each individual component, but I am having errors of the following kind:

```sh
1282: state is not legal for given parameters | weekend.cpp (96)
Shader program can not find the uniform location for hittables[2].type
1282: state is not legal for given parameters | weekend.cpp (164)
Shader program can not find the uniform location for hittables[2].sp.center
1282: state is not legal for given parameters | weekend.cpp (143)
Shader program can not find the uniform location for hittables[2].sp.radius
1282: state is not legal for given parameters | weekend.cpp (146)
Shader program can not find the uniform location for hittables[2].sp.mat_ptr.type
1282: state is not legal for given parameters | weekend.cpp (124)
Shader program can not find the uniform location for hittables[2].sp.mat_ptr.lam.albedo
```

Should I be using a different strategy to pass value to these structs ? Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems likely that the uniform was partially optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the most elegant solution, but I decided to make a big flat struct then parse it inside the shader.

Basically I transformed the above 
`uniform Hittable hittables[20];` into
`uniform NHittable hittables[20];` where `NHittable`
is defined as

```cpp
struct NHittable {
  int hittable_type;
  vec3 sphere_center;
  float sphere_radius;
  int material_type; // 0: lambert, 1: metal, 2: dielectric;
  vec3 lambert_albedo;
  vec3 metal_albedo;
  float metal_roughness;
  float dielectric_ref_idx;
};
```